# Angular Js Is not Displaying Data on Detail Page

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-routing

I'm new to angular js. Trying to use Angular Routing to show data from the database on a list page and a detail page. There is a table call employees in the database, I'm trying to use Angular Js $http service to display the list of employees and users can click each list to view details. I got it to listing results on the table.html page but it's not outpouring results on the view.html page. Any help, please? Thanks

Here is the angular script.

```
    /* App Module */
var employeeApp = angular.module('employeeApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'tableControllers'
]);

/* Controllers */

var tableControllers = angular.module('tableControllers', []);

tableControllers.controller('ListCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',
  function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('data/json.php').success(function(data) {
      $scope.employees = data;
    });
  }]);

tableControllers.controller('DetailCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$http',
  function($scope, $routeParams, $http) {
    $http.get('data/json.php').success(function(data) {
      $scope.employee = data;
    });
  }]);

employeeApp.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/page', {
        templateUrl: 'pages/table.html',
        controller: 'ListCtrl'
      }).
      when('/page/:employee_id', {
        templateUrl: 'pages/view.html',
        controller: 'DetailCtrl'
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/page'
      });
  }]);
```

Here is the Index File

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en" ng-app="employeeApp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
     <title>Graphic Editor</title>
     <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
     <link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
     <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
     <script src="js/angular-route.js"></script>
     <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <header></header>
  <section>
    <div class="container">
        <!-- angular templating -->
        <!-- this is where content will be injected -->
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"> </script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the view page

```
<table width="500" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td width="22%">Name</td><td width="22%">{{employee.firstName}} {{employee.firstName}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>employee</td><td>{{employee.employee}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Address</td><td>{{employee.addressLine1}} {{employee.addressLine2}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Action</td><td><a href="#/page/{{employee.employee_id}}">Edit</a></td>            
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<p>{{caption}}</p>
```

Comment: You're not passing the `$routeParams` to your `$http` call in your detail controller. You want be doing that, no?

Comment: can you show your html code?

Comment: @war1oc, I just add the html codes.

Comment: @duffn, I just need whatever works. I don't know much about angularjs. Just learning. I was following a tutorial but I put most of these piece together on my own. So can you show me how to pass the $routeParams to the $http.

Comment: you are calling the same url for both list and detail, can you do a `console.log(data)` in the success callback to see what data you are getting?